# Modifying hardware breakpoint(debug registers) at kernel space

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, breakpoints

I am trying to modify hardware breakpoints(x86 debug register) to set different addresses over iterations at kernel space(LKM). To modify the HW-breakpoint, I am disabling the perf event and setting the attr.bp_addr and re-enabling the event. I can register the HW-breakpoint for the first time but modifying them fails with kernel panic. What is the best way to modifying the HW-breakpoints at kernel space?

Comment: In [RaceHound](https://github.com/euspectre/racehound), I ended up calling `arch_uninstall_hw_breakpoint` to clear the HW breakpoint and then - `arch_install_hw_breakpoint` to set it again. See `hwbp_clear_impl` and `hwbp_set_impl` in https://github.com/euspectre/racehound/blob/master/core/racehound_main.c for an example. It has worked OK for me so far. `do_arch_uninstall_hwbp` and `do_arch_install_hwbp` in that code are aliases for `arch_uninstall_hw_breakpoint` and `arch_install_hw_breakpoint`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. This helps. Thank you.